# Issues with calculated field syntax

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Our school district uses O365 Sharepoint in the cloud.  I've been tasked with creating a calendar in Sharepoint for all users for conference rooms reservations.  I have NO experience with Sharepoint.  Most of this has been rather straightforward but I've hit a bump in the road.

I have a calculated column to figure out what the prep time is that the user needs so that it is shown on the calendar with the meeting request.

=[Start Time]-([Prep Hours]/24+[Prep Minutes]/1440)

This worked fine until one of our testers added a meeting that had NO prep time and then everything (workflows, adding it to the calendar) failed and he got an error.

I'm trying to account for a meeting with no prep time and have tried several (like 25+) different ways but keep getting a syntax error when I try to save it.

This is my latest - =[Start Time]-([Prep Hours]/24+[Prep Minutes]/1440), "[Start Time]")

I initially tried this one with ELSE which did not work.

Could someone please guide me to the enlightened path, please, where the calculated field will take into account a request WITH prep time and also without?

ETA - I'm not a programmer, nor do I have Sharepoint training, so unfortunately, I'm rather in the dark here.

Comment: I started out using this - =IF([Prep Hours]+[Prep Minutes]=0, THEN[Start Time]=[Start Time]) ELSE
[Start Time]-([Prep Hours]/24+[Prep Minutes]/1440)

Comment: Tried this - =IF (ISBLANK ([Prep Hours]),ISBLANK([Prep Minutes])&"-"[Start Time])

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out.

Here's the formula I used:

=IF(AND(VALUE([Prep Hours])=0,VALUE([Prep Minutes])=0),"[Start Time]",[Start Time]-([Prep Hours]/24+[Prep Minutes]/1440))